# Top user query shows wrong user reputation

Tags: support, reputation, user-accounts

In [top user query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/87307/top-n-users-in-the-country) based on Location, the results show wrong reputation value to me, I'm from Sri Lanka.

Query reads other users' updated reputation, but, for me, it reads older value. Where is the bug?

I tried another [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/130918/top-users-by-location) also, which also giving the same wrong results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Data.SE Help page](https://data.stackexchange.com/help)

> #### How often is the Stack Exchange Data Explorer updated?
>
> The data is updated early every Monday morning around 3:00 UTC. The last update was Feb 16 at 5:31.

So data on Data.SE is not latest. That's why your reputation is showing less as you have earned more than 300 reputation after 16th Feb. 2014.